# How to skip "Invalid argument" for OpenById and continue in code

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating simple tab with a call OpenById from cell.
If the cell is empty or with invalid ID script returns exception: invalid argument.

Is it possible to skip or ignore this error(exception) and continue in script from certain line of the script?

Here is example simple script. If the cell "H2" will empty, how to skip error?

Thanks for any help

```
function UpdateOld() {
var IDway = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Seznam TPM 2").getRange("h2");
var ID = IDway.getValue();
var Nazevway = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Seznam TPM 2").getRange("g3");
var Nazev = Nazevway.getValue();      
var TPM = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);
          SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(TPM);
```

Comment: You can check that ID is not null and that there isn't an error on the openById() with a try/catch

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: Thx for help, but i would like to find some method, how can i skip error to certain line of the script? If is it possible to use TryCatch also?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue

Comment: You can break or continue to a label and that's it but there is no goto in ecmascript.

Comment: Thx a lot for your help Cooper. I've already done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://lucymarmitchell.medium.com/using-then-catch-finally-to-handle-errors-in-javascript-promises-6de92bce3afc) could help, by using try > catch > finally you can tell the function what to do after a error has been thrown in the finally clause.